# Python count and group list

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
class distClass:
    dist = -1 #distance of current point from test point
    tag = '-' #tag of current point

list =[]
obj = distClass()  # one record's distance and tag
obj.dist = 1
obj.tag = 'F'
list .append(obj)
obj2 = distClass()  # one record's distance and tag
obj2.dist = 5
obj2.tag = 'F'
list .append(obj2)
obj3 = distClass()  # one record's distance and tag
obj3.dist = 10
obj3.tag = 'M'
list .append(obj3)
```

in this list the "F" exist 2 times
and the "M" exist 1 times

I need to get the tag that exists the most

(The distance does not important)
and I dont know what the tag is and how many type of tags exists

The goal is to know  what is the most tag for a list

```
+--------------------+-----+
|      distance      | tag |
+--------------------+-----+
|  2.23606797749979  |  F  |
|  3.3166247903554   |  M  |
| 5.744562646538029  |  F  |
| 5.744562646538029  |  M  |
|        18.0        |  M  |
| 21.095023109728988 |  F  |
| 22.090722034374522 |  M  |
| 23.08679276123039  |  M  |
| 39.02563260217571  |  M  |
+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Create a list of your tags, and use `Counter()` on said list. A oneline like `Counter([o.tag for o in list])` should work. Also, never call your variables `list` or one of the other builtins, it will break stuff.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A naive implementation via a loop seems straightforward. What specific technical problem do you have solving this?

Comment: That goal table has no sorting on tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was written before any massive changes to the original question. When the question was simply "I need to count how many times `x.tag` occurs.

```
from collections import Counter

class distClass:
    def __init__(self, dist=-1, tag='-'):
        self.dist = dist #distance of current point from test point
        self.tag = tag #tag of current point

my_list = []
my_list.append(distClass(1, 'F')) # one record's distance and tag
my_list.append(distClass(5, 'F')) # one record's distance and tag
my_list.append(distClass(10, 'M')) # one record's distance and tag

counts = Counter([o.tag for o in my_list])
print(counts.most_common(2))
```

This should count the different occurrences of your list elements `.tag`. And then proceed to print the two most common ones.

I also took the time to simplify the code a bit, as it seams that you don't work with the individual variables `obj2` etc, it's easier if you just store them in the list and if you never need to access the instance, just do `my_list[1]`. And I moved the default values of the `distClass` into the constructor function.

Comment: It's an 'agile' question :-)